# derbyJS - know who made the changes in real-time

Tags: google-docs, derbyjs

I am looking to [the derby multiplayer notepad](http://blog.derbyjs.com/2013/06/04/derby-v0-dot-5-0/). I am wondering what would be the best way to implement something like a cursor for the other people editing. Something like in google docs / etherpad for instance.

In general, I am looking for the following :

- is there something build-in derbyJS to tell who made the edits ? Or can we modify the way the synchronisation is done ?
- alternatively, what means of communications do I have, and which one would integrate better with derby ?

PS: I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752466/javascript-word-processor-editor-or-google-docs-architecture), but it doesn't really help me regarding the synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to enforce authentication in your application. I suggest you get the derby-auth npm module and use that to authenticate.

Once your user is authenticated you can then pass their handle (see [Passport](http://passportjs.org/)) back to every edit request to your server, then push that info back out to the connected clients.

See https://www.npmjs.org/package/derby-auth

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm a bit confused. What is the relationship between derby-auth (which is apparently looking for a maintainer right now) and passport (or are you talking about derby-passport) ?

Comment: hmm..derby-auth had a dependancy on passport. Derby-passport is middleware between derby and passport, I would stick to using that project now since d-auth is not being maintained